# Two-way Wilkinson divider: why is R₂ = Z·K and R₃ = Z/K?

Tags: rf, microwave, divider

I am trying to understand why R<sub>2</sub> = K · Z<sub>0</sub> and R<sub>3</sub> = Z<sub>0</sub> / K.

I get the power is not equally distributed over both ports, but why is one multiplying and the other dividing?

[image]

Comment: In my opinion it is an adaptation for maximum power transfer. That is, the impedance of the upper section at lamda quarters is: Z02=K∙Z0 = sqrt(2)∙Z0 = R2 while for the lower one it is Z03=Z0/K = R3. For further information see: "Introduction to microwave circuits" chap.: 12, by Robert J. Weber, IEEE PRESS

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson_power_divider

Answer (score 1):

[microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110) simulation of this circuit, green and red curves are the same.

Wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson_power_divider)

[image]

With \$P2/P3 = k^2 = 2^2\$, we have this simulation.

[image]

**Don't yet found?**

See this simulation ... at ~ 250 MHz

[image]

**The Some voltage** appears at outputs vo1 and vo2 **-> vo1=vo and vo2=vo**.
This occurs **only** if the factor k is used ... And it is not "intuitive".

As it is across resistors, the "power" divides easily.
Then it is \$powR2=vo^2/(zoo*k)\$ and \$powR3=vo^2/(zoo/k)\$ ...

If  \$pow=vo^2/(zoo))\$  , then \$powR2=pow/k\$ and \$powR3=pow*k\$
and finally : \$ powR3/powR2 = k^2 \$ ... **cqfd** or **QED**.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You've shown a simulation but it doesn't explain *why*.

Comment: It is a "guess" of the writer in Wikipedia. Just apply the "transmission lines" theory. An unfavorable vote is therefore contraindicated. <<< D.M. Pozar, Microwave Engineering, Third Edition, John Wiley & Sons: New York, 2005 >>>

Comment: OP is asking *why* is it K and 1/K - an intuitive explanation, not a simulation or possible values.

Comment: @Jason see the answer update ...